# Parse.com onListItemClick not displaying any detail information

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I am trying out this code i have that uses Parse.com to get restaurant names and put the in a listView.
When you click on one of the names then it takes you to a details page where you can get detail information about the restaurant. 
Problem is when i click on the name on the ListView it goes to the details pages but displays nothing.
I am new to android and parse and don't fully understand how it should work.

here is the code in my mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private CustomAdapter urgentTodosAdapter;
private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
private ListView listView;
List<ParseObject> Name =new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this,"RestaurantDetail");
    urgentTodosAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView.setAdapter(urgentTodosAdapter);
    urgentTodosAdapter.loadObjects();

// Binds the Adapter to the ListView
listView.setAdapter(urgentTodosAdapter);
// Capture button clicks on ListView items
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
        Intent random1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
        if (Name.size() > i)

            // Pass data "name" followed by the position
            random1.putExtra("Name", Name.get(i).getString("Name"));

        // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
        startActivity(random1);

    }
});
}
}
```

and my customAdapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("RestaurantDetail");

  /* query.whereEqualTo("Name", true);*/

            return query;
        }

    });

}

@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {

        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_main, null);
    }
    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("Logo");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
        todoImage.loadInBackground();
    }

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("Name"));
    return v;
}
}
```

and the class that suppose to display the name of the restaurant etc.

```
@ParseClassName("RestaurantDetail")
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {

// Declare Variables
protected TextView txtname;
String Name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from SingleItemView.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.single_item_view);

    txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
    Intent random1 = getIntent();
    // Get the name
    Name = random1.getStringExtra("Name");

    // Locate the TextView in singleitemview.xml

    // Load the text into the TextView
    txtname.setText(Name);

}
}
```

Comment: Move your 'onCreate' code to a different activity - to a custom adapter.  The 'RestaurantDetail' class is just for parse class initialization and using set/getter.  If you still need the code, let me know and i'll post it for you.

Comment: AndroidDev21921 , if you can please post it. much appreciated :)

Comment: Glad it worked - if you have any questions, just let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my comment in the OP's comment section to get some context:

Answer:

In your MainActivity you didn't create a query to add to the adapter.  Take a look below and adjust the ParseQuery to your needs:

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private CustomAdapter urgentTodosAdapter;
private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
private ListView listView;
List<ParseObject> Name =new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //I'm not sure how you initialized your custom adapter - i'll show you how i did it, but yours might work too
    urgentTodosAdapter = new urgentTodosAdapter(MainActivity.this, new ArrayList<RestaurantDetail>());

    listView.setAdapter(urgentTodosAdapter);

    //Here is where you forgot to add your ParseQuery for 'Restaurants'

    ParseQuery<RestaurantDetail> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(RestaurantDetail.class);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<RestaurantDetail>() {
        public void done(List<RestaurantDetail> resutarantList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                if (resutarantList.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < resutarantList.size(); i++) {
                        //you forgot to do this - didn't add anything for the adapter to show.
                        urgentTodosAdapter.add(resutarantList.get(i));

                    }

                } else {

                    // do something if empty

                }
            } else {

                // do something if null
            }
        }
    });

    //This is fine here, but you can also do the same in your adapter class; I'll keep this here and show you where to put it
    //in the adapter as well.

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent random1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
            if (Name.size() > i)

                // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                random1.putExtra("Name", Name.get(i).getString("Name"));

            // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
            startActivity(random1);

        }
    });
}
}
```

CustomAdapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RestaurantDetail> {
private final Context mContext;
private List<RestaurantDetail> restrauants;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RestaurantDetail> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.include_restaurants, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.restrauants = objects;
}


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.include_restaurants, null);
    }

    ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("Logo");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
        todoImage.loadInBackground();
    }

    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    titleTextView.setText(object.getString("Name"));

    //this is also where you can handle to onClick stuff

    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });


    return v;
}
}
```

Initialize your parse class: this is also where you can put your getters/setters.

```
@ParseClassName("YourClassNameInYourDBHere") 
public class ResuaurantDetail(your class here) extends ParseObject
{

 }
```

Comment: AndroidDev21921, i got that working but my next question is, How do i now get that data from that activity into another activity using button click??

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the data, you can just use intent extras (plenty of answers on SO about this, but i can post if needed), and then using that intent extra info in the other activity..  

Or you can create a data model that stores it globally.  Sending info as intent extras are far easier (atleast for me), but varies case by case.

Comment: AndroidDev21921 , could you please show me an example. i am new to android and still learning it.